# This is for Duck

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

As promised I have crafted a homonym riddle just for @Duck. With the recent spike in homophone riddles, I figured it was time. I finally figured out what word to use, so can you tell me which word it is?

> Depart quickly, turn back now; this little riddle is going to be foul.
>
> Take a plunge, into the fire; like learning to walk on top of a wire.
>
> Don’t cower, nor cringe; there’s no need to fear; solving this riddle, won’t take a year.
>
> Tipping already? Biting your nails? The next clue is, I am used within sails.
>
> Help is here, an unsung hero; also known as batsman’s zero.
>
> If that’s not enough, then I’ll get you out; my vehicle floats, there’s no need to pout.
>
> One last clue, before I must leave; defined as another, a mollusk I be.

What am I?

Comment: +1 and + favorite

Comment: Oi, you stealing my theme of Meta Riddles?

Comment: If you’re talking about your massive Riley riddles then no; they are great though! If not then can you provide a link so I can see those too? I’ve enjoyed your riddles.

Comment: @Duck meh too :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you

> Duck?!?

Depart quickly, turn back now; this little riddle is going to be foul.

> Duck-out, and (foul), are types of birds (thanks Jafe :)

Take a plunge, into the fire; like learning to walk on top of a wire.

> Plunge like dunk and dip is synonymous with duck.

Don’t cower, nor cringe; there’s no need to fear; solving this riddle, won’t take a year.

> Cower is another synonym like duck down or cower.

Tipping already? Biting your nails? The next clue is, I am used within sails.

> Doetch is Dutch for cloth, which makes up sails. Doetch later turns to Duck in the English language. (From R.D and Duck thanks :D)

Help is here, an unsung hero; also known as batsman’s zero.

> I typed in "Batsman's Zero" and duck was the answer.

If that’s not enough, then I’ll get you out; my vehicle floats, there’s no need to pout.

> Ducks float, also pouting is close to a duck face (Thanks fogmeister)

One last clue, before I must leave; defined as another, a mollusk I be.

> And also there is a mollusk named the Pacific Geoduck(From R.D and Duck thanks :D)

But,

> This puzzle IS for Duck.

Comment: rot 13 => Qbrgpu vf Qhgpu sbe pybgu, juvpu znxrf hc fnvyf. Qbrgpu yngre gheaf gb Qhpx va gur ratyvfu ynathntr. Naq nyfb gurer vf n zbyyhfx anzrq gur Cnpvsvp Trbqhpx. Fubhyq unir orra trbqhqr vzb

Comment: rot13[n yvggyr sbhy/sbjy cha guebja va gurer nf jryy] :)

Comment: I only decrypted the rot13 after I did the answer

Comment: In cricket to be out with 0 runs is to go “out for a duck” that’s the batsman’s zero

Comment: Also, no need to pout. Pouting lips are known as “duck face” poses.

Comment: I knew batsman’s zero was a giveaway.

Comment: Hehehe, great puzzle :D

Answer (score 5):

Adding on to @quantumtwinkie answer

Mollusk I may be

> Are you talking about the geoduck?

I am used within sails

> Sailboats sometimes have duck cloth