# This is for Duck (Original Version)

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, acrostic

Well, the [first riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/this-is-for-duck) seemed too easy; I knew for a fact that [batsman's zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_(cricket)) was going to be a dead give away. I had originally written the riddle a different way, and in-fact would like to share it with the community. I had to flip it over and tweak it a little since the first line was no longer true; but it remains 98% true to the original.

Now, you already know from the last riddle, that the homonym in question is (put in spoiler tag for those who'd like to solve this one in its purest form):

> Duck

However, the requirements for this riddle are a bit different. In order for an answer to be accepted you'll need to answer the following:

- What is the homonym?
- How does the homonym relate to each reference?
- What words are hidden in the riddle?

For those who think this is a duplicate, it is not. It is an entirely different form of the previous riddle; and though the answer to one of the above requirements is clear, the other two requirements are not. This is not a simple, research and answer type question. I've hidden some words (as stated above) that you'll have to find. So without further ado:

> After the last one, let's start a new canvas; back to the solving, we all need some practice.
>
> Less erratic the challenge, but words you must spot; tedious, frivolous, dumbfounded plot.
>
> Approaching the end, but head to the west; Indians have hints, at puzzles, the best.
>
> Black belly, white face, solve this with grace; prefix to scar, the suffix bled in a race.
>
> I'm a bird, yet a train, used in war, just the same; a lot to find here, autopsy my game.
>
> Out for a zero, just ditch the bat; dear, there is nothing, left in my hat.

**Hint 1**:

> This one is fun, like twisted fate; find hidden words, of which there are eight.

**Hint 2**:

> Refer to the riddle, you'll get your fix; references hiding, of which there are six.

**Hint 3**:

> While searching the riddle, look for some fowl; though I must warn you, its not an owl.

**Hint 4**:

> Surely you have, a partial by now; two partials conjoined, may help you out.

**Hint 5**:

> Hint 4 wasn't helpful, not alone at least; add words together, on birds you shall feast.

**Hint 6**:

> A Riley contained, but not truly clear; synonyms you'll need, the answer draws near.

**Hint 7**:

> The words which you seek, are hard to find; they can be found, all in due time.
> Break down the puzzle, read line by line; look at the words, and how they combine.

**Hint 8**:

> Autopsy is hard, this riddle more so; as for this reference, the Navy may know.

**Hint 9**:

> David is great, his view quite unique; McCallum knows all, what he says makes you think.

I wish you all the best of luck!

---

**Note**: If you leave a down-vote, please explain how I can improve my post.

Comment: Ooh, another one not answered by quantumtwinkie

Comment: @Duck hahah we’ll see.... Also, to OP, great riddle! $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: Who knows, @QuantumTwinkie may make an appearance! Also, thanks for the feedback! I had a fun time writing the riddle as it was not only difficult, but, well, the Making Of should clarify the rest! :)

Comment: I am thinking of perhaps writing a Making Of for every puzzle I make. I reckon it will serve a very interesting thought. Perhaps the Puzzling Stack Exchange could develop an answer of this particular structure that we may write in :P

Comment: Look to either my post for Hunting Season is Open; or Riddled and Dismembered by Hugh Meyers! They both have very good layouts.

Comment: I think some of the hidden things are multiple words. Does the count specified in one of the hints count *words* or *things*?

Comment: (I think the answer has to be things rather than words.)

Comment: Tis both in fact. The hints are more literal, while solving the riddle is more lateral.

Comment: Hmm. I'm pretty sure I've found more than eight _words_. Ah well.

Comment: Only way to find out is to answer and get feedback! :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too, which is why I just posted an answer with a bunch of holes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Duck, there is

> an acrostic yielding ALABIO, our first hidden duck breed.

Now let's turn to the individual lines.

```
After the last one, let's start a new canvas; back to the solving, we all need some practice.
```

> Hidden duck type: CANVASBACK.

```
Less erratic the challenge, but words you must spot; tedious, frivolous, dumbfounded plot.
```

> Hidden duck types: (Australian?) SPOTTED. LESSER.

```
Approaching the end, but head to the west; Indians have hints, at puzzles, the best.
```

> Hidden duck type: WEST INDIAN (whistling).

```
Black belly, white face, solve this with grace; prefix to scar, the suffix bled in a race.
```

> Hidden duck types: BLACK BELLIED (whistling), WHITE FACED (whistling). I think the prefix is MAR and the suffix (simply) BLED, so that MARBLED is a third hidden duck-type here. If the "race" has significance, though, I haven't spotted it.

```
I'm a bird, yet a train, used in war, just the same; a lot to find here, autopsy my game.
```

> A duck is a bird. The [Mallard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LNER_Class_A4_4468_Mallard) was the fastest steam locomotive ever made. The thing used in war is probably a DUKW. In comments nikki points out that there is a TV show called NCIS in which one character, Donald Horatio "Ducky" Mallard, is responsible for performing autopsies.

```
Out for a zero, just ditch the bat; dear, there is nothing, left in my hat.
```

> When a (cricket) batsman is dismissed without making any runs he is said to be out "for a duck". (I think this derives from the use of "duck egg" to mean zero, because of the shape.) "Duck", like "dear", is an affectionate term of address in some places. My guess is that "nothing left in my hat" is just referring to those duck eggs again, but I could be wrong.

Hints:

> Eight words, six references: we have seven hidden duck-types so far, unless MALLARD counts as a "word" as well as a "reference". I think the "references" are things like the Mallard train, "duck" the term of endearment, etc.; I have exactly six of those so far (bird, train, DUKW, autopsies, zero runs, "dear"). The fowl, obviously, is a goose. Er, I mean a duck. I'm not sure what to make of hints 4 and 5 (partials, conjoined, feast). I've got the Riley. Hint 7 doesn't seem like it actually says anything. Hint 8 refers to the fact that NCIS is a Navy agency. Hint 9 is a giveaway for the same part of the puzzle; David McCallum is the actor who plays Mallard.

History:

> Some things I thought in earlier versions of this answer: my first guess for the train was "Duck" in the *Thomas the Tank Engine* children's books; my second the [DB Class 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DB_Class_403) train, also known as "Donald Duck". I thought the autopsy thing might be DUC, abbreviating "Death by unnatural causes".

Comment: You have six of the eight hidden words, and four of the references. The reference to a train is incorrect, and there is a final reference in that same passage. One of those hidden words is the embedded Riley. Yes, Black belly, white face was correct! :D

Comment: I have another attempt at the train, and have found another reference in that passage. If those are correct then perhaps I am on 6/6 references and just need two more hidden words (including the Riley)?

Comment: Unfortunately both are still wrong; you'll understand the train once you find it! As for the autopsy relationship, you'll have to dive deep. I'll add a new hint for that since it is rather difficult to find.

Comment: Bah! Will keep thinking, then.

Comment: Added the hint for you! You're closing in, I think the Riley is probably the hardest part.

Comment: I have another guess for the train. Still thinking about everything else.

Comment: You've got the train! Now for the autopsy, just follow the same!

Comment: Well, I think I have the Riley. Still blanking on the autopsy, and it's bedtime. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Good job on the Riley portion! The last reference is definitely a knowledge based reference.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan rot 13(V guvax gur nhgbcfl vf ersreevat gb Qhpxl sebz APVF)

Comment: Ah, that seems possible. That's a thing I would never have got for myself in a hundred years.

Comment: ... oh, actually, seeing hint 9, I probably would :-). But I hadn't noticed that hint before.

Comment: You have everything but the final word. All references are found; look back to the second line to find it. I promise it's there.

Comment: Thanks @PerpetualJ for taking pity on me and filling in the last duck type :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan LOL You put in a lot of hard work on this answer, so I didn't want the bounty to go to waste, especially since you were only missing a single duck lol

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer:

> Alabio goes down and there is an alabio duck. Also, on the first line use the first letter of every other on and it spells out "all acts as." This plane was used in war: Grumman J2F Duck

Comment: Keep working it! Lol

Comment: I will keep updating my answer

Comment: What is all acts as alabio

Comment: Added a new hint to help you out; you're off to a decent start. However, rot13(gurer'f bayl bar npebfgvp); keep up the good work and you'll get there!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_J2F_Duck Hmmmm...

Comment: Are you gonna steal it away?

Answer (score 2):

## Partial Answer:

Adding to the  @[GarethMcCaughan's ♦ answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71066/this-is-for-duck-original-version/72207#72207), could another hidden word be

> **TEAL**?

```
Less erratic the challenge, but words you must spot; tedious, frivolous, dumbfounded plot
```

> If you get the first two letters of **te**dious, **fr**ivolous, **du**mbfounded, you can get a secret message.

> A **te**al is a **fr**eshwater **du**ck; the definition of a type of duck known as a **TEAL**.

> This message is less erratic because there is an obvious pattern here once found. A way to find this pattern is to look at the following words: le**ss**, e**rr**atic, and cha**ll**enge. As highlighted in bold, they each have two of the same letters, hinting out this pattern.

```
Approaching the end, but head to the west; Indians have hints, at puzzles, the best.
```

> @GarethMcCaughan most likely figured out the hidden duck in this passage, but

could another one be

> The **INDIAN RUNNER**?

> The word "**hints**" sounds like "**sprints**" which might refer to running; the word **erratic** sounds like **erect** and this duck stands **erect** (like penguins); the word **dumbfounded** sounds like **domestic** and this duck is a breed of *Anas platyrhynchos* ***domesticus***.

```
Black belly, white face, solve this with grace; prefix to scar, the suffix bled in a race.
```

> This might be a reference to [*Sophia Grace & Rosie's Royal Adventure: Magic Duck*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRIySEm1Vps). The word **solve** sounds like **Sophia** and the line also contains the word **grace**; the name **Rosie** sounds like **roses**, which are red (like **scars** and **blood**).

Comment: @PerpetualJ is this on the right track?

Comment: Gareth is only missing the reference to autopsy, everything else is correct in his answer; I’ll look your current over and get back with you unless you’d like to update your answer and attempt what’s missing.

Comment: @PerpetualJ Damn, I thought my first explanation had to be one of the references. That is some awesome coincidence, then. I will try and figure out the autopsy reference :P

Comment: @PerpetualJ The only thing I can get is that another word for autopsy is "necropsy" and that starts with the same letter as "navy" :\

Comment: Think more of movies and tv